# Lapack routine dgesv mlogit mlogit in R

Tags: r, error-handling, mlogit, singular

I am getting an error in **R** when I try to run mlogit.

I try to estimate the following:

```
logit3 <- mlogit(choice~1|prod1+prod2+camp1+camp2+salm1+salm2+orig1+orig2+price1+price2, data=CNLdata)
```

and the error appeared is the following:

> logit3 <-   mlogit(choice~1|prod1+prod2+camp1+camp2+salm1+salm2+orig1+orig2+price1+price2, data=CNLdata)
>       Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) :
>         system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.49164e-20

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Data example:

[image]

Comment: This means you cannot generate a solution, probably because the system is underdefined.   BTW,  posting a link to an image of a dataset is kinda pointless.  You should post a small, reproducible example in your question, or post a link to the data itself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How could the system be properly defined. I have to state that I am not the most advanced user of R.